# How to work with each individual word in a char** datatype

Tags: arrays, c, split, char

I have a function that returns all words entered per line as an array of words as follows:

```
char **commands(const char *command){
    char **commands_list;
    int count,pos,len,i;
    for(pos=0,count=0;;count++){
        pos+= strspn(command+pos," \t\r\n");
        if (command[pos] == '\0') break;
        len = strcspn(command+pos," \t\r\n");
        pos += len;
    }
    commands_list = malloc(sizeof(*commands_list) * (count+1));
    if(commands_list == NULL) return NULL;
    for(pos = 0, i=0;;i++){
        pos += strspn(command+pos," \t\r\n");
        if(command[pos] == '\0') break;
        if(command[pos] == '>') break;
        len = strcspn(command+pos," \t\r\n");
        commands_list[i] = strndup(command+pos,len);
        if (commands_list[i] == NULL){
            while(i-->0) free(commands_list[i]);
            free(commands_list);
            return NULL;
        }
        pos+=len;
    }
    commands_list[i] = NULL;
    return commands_list;
}
```

Now in another function I want to loop through each of these words and split them up where there is a >.

So for example if the input in the terminal is ls tests/folder-test>/tmp/output then the returned output is `{"ls","tests/folder-test>/tmp/output"}` but I want it to convert it to `{"ls","tests/folder-test"}` and return the tmp/output part.

Comment: Time to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.